# How to load USDZ Models with animations and textures using ThreeJS

Tags: three.js, service-worker, 3d-model, usdz, usd

I am building a web-based 3D viewer. It is working perfectly for other file types (.fbx, .glb, .obj, ...)

It gets complicated when I want to load *.usdz* files.
To do that I am using [github.com/ponahoum/three-usdz-loader](https://github.com/ponahoum/three-usdz-loader)

I am doing that because I want to support the binary and the ASCII format. The ThreeJS original version does not work with *.usdz* files that contain binary files.

The current version:

- is able to load still (non-animated) models
- is not able to display any textures -> everything is pink
- is not able to load animated models (the mesh loading fails and the scene stays empty)

This is pretty much identical to the demo linked in the README.md (https://www.usdz-viewer.net/). My code is also identical to the exmaple in the README.md.

I would leave it at that, but the README.md explicitly states, that animations **are** supported.

So here is the question: Does anyone know, how I can get the loader to work (with animations/ ideally even textures) or is there any alternative that works?

Comment: A little more information: https://github.com/ponahoum/three-usdz-loader/issues/6